# NodeJS - Identify file type when getObject from Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have a S3 Bucket with many type of files (since images to PDF).
I need to identify the file type when I am using s3.getObject to return it appropriately.

I have this code:

```
module.exports.getAttachedFile = async (fileName) => {

try {
    let s3 = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: 'my_access_key',
        secretAccessKey: 'my_secret_key'
    });
    
    let params = {
        Bucket: 'attached-files',
        Key: fileName
    };

    const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    return data.Body;
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return e;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can get the MIME type by calling `data.ContentType`.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html#API_GetObject_ResponseElements) you can see all the attributes of the GetObject Response.